# Failed to open TCP connection Ruby HTTParty on macOS 10.11, but not in Windows 10

Tags: ruby, macos, tcp

I am currently on macOS 10.11

> Error: Failed to open TCP connection to rugby.statbunker.com:443
>   (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known).

However the code runs in Windows 10.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'HTTParty'
ROOT_LINK ='https://rugby.statbunker.com/players/getPlayerInternationalStats?player_id='
playerID=31659
pageLink = ROOT_LINK + playerID.to_s
wbPage = HTTParty.get(pageLink)
puts wbPage.length.to_s
```